# Content-dependent div with labels

Tags: css, html, width

```
<div id="combobox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="tag3"
        name="checkbox" onclick="toggleTag('tag3')"/>DialogProc</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="tag2"
        name="checkbox" onclick="toggleTag('tag2')"/>fds</label><br/>
</div>
```

I'm using `div` as a container for checkboxes with labels. Corresponding css:

```
div#combobox
{
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

And this does exactly what I want - vertical scrollbar (no horizontal one), capped height and content-dependent width. With one exception - it doesn't take vertical scrollbar's width into account. So when there are few lines/checkboxes and the vertical scrollbar isn't needed - the width of the `div` is the width of the widest checkbox. But when the scrollbar appears, the width of the `div` is unchanged:
[image]

The `label` is broken into 2 lines. I fixed this with `span`:

```
<span><label><input type="checkbox" id="tag4"
    name="checkbox" onclick="toggleTag('tag4')"/>InitializeWindow</label></span><br/>
```

and:

```
span
{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

but the `div`'s width is still incorrect:

[image]

Is there any way to get make the `div` take scrollbar's width into account with just html/css? If not, what's the best way to do it with javascript?

Comment: did you find solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

So you can check if there is a scroll activated:

```
$('#combobox').hasScrollBar(); // returns true if there's a `vertical` scrollbar
```

after that you can expand the size of your `div` with some javascript...this would probably work for you:

`$('#combobox').css("width",$('#combobox').width+13);` //this is just an example to use 13px but you need to test it in all browsers to see how it all works

Comment: I'm not using jQuery although I pretty much did what you described - checked if there's a scrollbar and changed the width with JS accordingly. Can't mark it as accepted due to jQuery, though.

Comment: @NPS ok no problem, I just wanted to see if I helped